# linear operator T is defined over a finite dimensional vector space X

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose a linear operator T is defined over a finite dimensional vector space X, what can we say about the continuity of the operator T. Are finite dimension of the vector space and continuity of the linear operator in any way related

Answer (score 0):

Yes in fact they are related. Any linear operator defined on a finite dimensional normed space is continuous.

To see this let $X$ be a finite-dimensional normed space and let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be a basis for $X$. Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the original norm on $X$. Define another norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ on $X$ by $\|x\| = \sum_\limits{k=1}^{n}|x_k|$ where $x=x_1e_1+\cdots+x_ne_n$. Since any two norms on a finite-dimensional normed space are equivalent so there exists $c>0$ such that $\|x\|_1\leq c\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$. Now for any operator $T$ on $X$ let $M= \max\{\|Te_1\|,\ldots, \|Te_n\|\}$, then for any $x\in X$
\begin{equation}
\|Tx\| \leq \sum_\limits{k=1}^{n}\|Te_k\||x_k|\leq Mc\|x\|.
\end{equation}
Thus $T$ is a bounded linear operator and hence is continuous.